# Can't run the shell command through html form using python cgi

Tags: python, html, apache, shell, cgi

I want to copy the folder from one server to another by executing the following shell command 
sshpass -p 'XXXX' scp -r root@X.X.X.X(ip): Sourcedirectory(sdr) DestinationDirectory(ddr) ,
using the python script and web GUI.

I have html form page with 3 inputs (ip,sdr,ddr), when I pass these inputs through web page to the python script these inputs are copied to their respective location , but the command is not being executed and rest of the lines in python file gets executed.

if the same script is executed by command line it works.

Can anyone help me where Im missing out.

The following is the code I used.

Python script:

```
            #!/usr/bin/python
            import gzip,glob,os.path
            import os
            import subprocess

             # Import modules for CGI handling 
               import cgi, cgitb 
               import time

               # Create instance of FieldStorage 
               # Get data from fields
                 form = cgi.FieldStorage()
                 ip = form.getvalue('ip')
                 sdr = form.getvalue('sdr')
                 ddr = form.getvalue('ddr')
                 import sys


                class RunCmd(object):
                      def cmd_run(self, cmd):
                      self.cmd = cmd
                      subprocess.call(self.cmd, shell=True)

               id=("sshpass -p 'XXXX' scp -r root@%s:%s %s" %(ip,sdr,ddr))
               b = RunCmd()
               b.cmd_run(id)
```

Comment: And while you are at it, kindly remove unnecessary indentation.

Comment: yes it is minimized

Comment: @rskkumar do you have root access to run that command?

Comment: @ChaminWickramarathna yes I have root access

Comment: the command should issue some output. Do you see some output? what about the return code (returned by `call`) ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : It is 0